# Any C# WinApplication with Install Sheild Building to .exe with SqlServer Database

Tags: c#, .net

i have compile the application to Setup.exe with Install Sheild in Visual studio 2015 with SQL server 2012. The application work on my computer but when i transfer Setup.exe it to clients computer it didnt work generate problem with client computer.

Need A way to handle the application with

1. I have attached the database to SQLSERVER Managment studio.
2. I have
   change configuration File Data Source=""to client computer Address
   but still not working.

   public static string GetConnection()

   ```
   {

       return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyCon"].ConnectionString;

   }
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnection());
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select EmpID from RegForm",con);
      int i= Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
      if(i!=0)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("value type is " + i);
           con.Close();
           MessageBox.Show("Connection is closed ");
       }



   }
   ```

I just want that this compile application Start working with setting path in configuration DataSource Attribute nd the programming start working with Active Database

Comment: That doesn't look like valid sql.

Comment: Lars Tech :the connection string is in App.config file let me share it with you.  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="MyCon" connectionString="Data Source=RISESTAR\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Z-JanPayroll;Integrated Security=True"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Doesn't change my comment.  Look at your query.  Copy and paste your code next time.

Comment: change the query; on my machine it work fine but on client machine it didnt work

Comment: You haven't told us what the errors are.  "not working" is not a good diagnosis for us.  Give us the exact exception message you are seeing.

Comment: The Connection was not closed.The connection's Current state is open. When the button is click second time but the Query didnt execute because the connection to database is not set could u pls tell me how to set the connection to database.

Comment: That's a conflicting comment you have going on there.  For the connection to be open means the connection works, but then you say the connection is not set.  Obviously, you should be closing your connections every time you are done with them.  Easiest way to do that is with the using-block pattern: `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnection())) { ... }`